# GridView inside ScrollView pushes down Footer view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have toolbar on top.  A Scrollview in the middle with ContraintLayout as child. Inside the ContraintLayout I have a gridview. As I add items it pushes down the footer below. I am experiencing this with both relativelayout and linear layout as root parent. It just pushes everything down and out of sight. I cannot see the footer. Everything just gets pushed downward. No matter that I set scrollview as being above the footer etc. or different weights if I use a linear layout. It always pushes down my footer!!!

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:rowCount="6"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" >
                <Button
                     android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Button" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Button" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button10"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button11"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button12"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </GridLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>


THIS IS PUT INSIDE HERE:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.administrator.demoapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_note_memo"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_note_memo" />
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_plus"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_plus_white"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="283dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_search"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_plus"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_search"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="283dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_media"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_search"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/media_icons_team_white"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="283dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textNote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Note"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_note_memo" />
            <!--
             <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                 android:id="@+id/toolbarGuideline"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" /> -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivScan"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_note_memo"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivPayCode"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconfont_scan" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textScan"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Scan"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivScan"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivScan" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPayCode"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivDiscount"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivScan"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivScan"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconfont_paycode" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textPayCode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pay Code"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"

                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivPayCode"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivPayCode" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivDiscount"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivScan"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivDangmianfu"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPayCode"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconfont_discount" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDiscount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Discount"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivDiscount"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivDiscount" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivDangmianfu"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivScan"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivDiscount"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconfont_dangmianfu_yellow" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDianmianful"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mianfu"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivDangmianfu"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivDiscount" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <include
        layout="@layout/scroll_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scroll_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_front_huabei"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_confont_koubeilogo"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconfont_huabei" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_confont_koubeilogo"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_icon_social_team_black"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_front_huabei"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconfont_koubeilogo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_icon_social_team_black"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_iconfont_zhuanzhang"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_confont_koubeilogo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_social_team_black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/unredMsgButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_icon_social_team_black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_icon_social_team_black"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_iconfont_zhuanzhang"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_icon_social_team_black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconfont_zhuanzhang" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please give more detail xml codes

Comment: Ok, I added all the xml codes. I have grid than banner than more grid items this i the content between header and footer so I was looking to add one gridview than banner than another gridview all inside a scrollview but its not working!

Comment: I need someone to explain why a scrollview would ever push stuff down inside a relative layout or linear layout? Why? Why does the scrollview keep growing downward?